# Installer Project giving error in VS2k8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, installation, windows-installer

I have a installer project on VS 2k8, .net 3.5. Its giving me the following error:

Error   1   Invalid icon file 'MSDN Magazine Managed Preview Handlers', located in 'Application Folder' C:\Users\jaminator\Desktop\APPreview\Handler\InstallPreviewHandlers\InstallPreviewHandlers.vdproj   InstallPreviewHandlers

It is a demo application which i was trying to modify to make my own so i changed the icon since then i am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the setup project is unable to find the icon thats why its throwing exception. Try choosing the Icon again.

1. Rebuild your main application
2. Goto your setup project .. then Application Folder
3. Click on the MSDN Magazine** Handlers
4. In the property window again choose the Icon
5. Build your setup.

Comment: i am lost in the 3rd step of you rsoltion in application folder i have a Primarry output from a project and i icon which i want to display

Comment: my main project is running and building fine its only the setup project that giving error

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS 2005 but encountered the same issue:

- Left Click on your setup project in the solution explorer
- in the properties window to the right

  - select AddRemoveProgramsIcon
  - click browse
  - find the icon file in your File System for this setup project (go back and add it if it isn't added already)
- Build your project, this should fix the issue.